# How to find documents with title like "*.pdf" in alfresco lucene search

Tags: javascript, lucene, alfresco

I need to restrict search to documents with title with suffix ".pdf" in JavaScript

Right now I add to the lucene search this:

```
ls += ' +@cm\\:title:"*\\.pdf" '
```

It almost does the job, but it also returns titles like:

```
Cloud Strategy - Presentation (PDF)
```

What is the correct solution?

Comment: Do you really mean `title`? Wouldn't searching for files where the `cm:name` ended in .pdf be more what you're after?

Comment: I'm really looking for `title`. I agree that `title` shouldn't have an extension. I need to make a list of documents with 'wrong' `title`, so it can be fixed.

Comment: how to know default properties in alfresco like user first name,last name email id etc...i want to make lucene query for getting noderef through specific emailId..

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried with a simple:

```
ls += ' +@cm\\:title:".pdf" ';
```

It worked for me on a test example.